# How can I check if laravel count result is null or not

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, controller

I have this code :

```
$status = htransaksi::find(auth()->user()->id)->where('Status','Open')->count();
if ($status != 0)
{
    $idhtrans = htransaksi::select('id')->where('User_ID', auth()->user()->id)->where('Status', 'Open')->first();
    $shopcart = DB::table('detiltransaksis')->join('Barangs', 'Barangs.id', '=', 'detiltransaksis.barang_Id')->where('htrans_Id', $idhtrans->id)->get();
    return view('home')->with('barang', $barang)->with('jenis', $jenis)->with('shopcount',$shopcart);
}
else
{
    return view('home')->with('barang', $barang)->with('jenis', $jenis);
}
```

This code checks, is there any item in your shopping cart? If there is an item then return that shopping cart and when there is no item it shows some error that say

> Call to a member function where() on null

Anyone knows how to fix this?
I'm new to Laravel and sorry if this is such a newbie question.

Edit : 
The error point to

```
 $status = htransaksi::find(auth()->user()->id)->where('Status', 'Open')->count();
```

Comment: Which `where()` is it? Debug it to the exact line. Some pointers: 1) you shouldnt be using `DB::table()`, instead use an Eloquent model for `'detiltransaksis'`. 2) the first line's `where()` statement is not an SQL where but a PHP where. Read up on https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Comment: Which `where()` are we talking about? Can you post the entire error?

Comment: the error pointed to 
$status = htransaksi::find(auth()->user()->id)->where('Status','Open')->count();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I see `htransaksi::find(auth()->user()->id)->where('Status','Open')->count();` is incorrect. You cannot use `where()` function after `find()`.

Let's try:

```
$status = htransaksi::where('User_ID',auth()->user()->id)->where('Status','Open')->count();
```

Comment: i see, but find and where is doing fine if there is some item in the cart.
any suggestion/code to resolve my problem??

Comment: This is actually wrong `where()` is also a PHP function to search iterateables.This is why the code works if `htransaksi::find(auth()->user()->id)`is not null

Comment: @EricSugiharto try my solution. Believe old guy. :)

Comment: You could also chain `exists()` instead of `count()` if you only need to query for the record existence (it would instruct the query builder to use an `EXISTS` query rather than a `COUNT`). That function would just return a boolean value

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Auth::check()) {
  $status = htransaksi::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('Status','Open')->count();
  ... your "normal logic"
} else {
  $error_handling_user_not_logged_in();
}
```

The reason why I added the Auth::check() check is to make sure that the user is really logged in, feed free to remove it if you already know this because of middleware/request validation.

You code did not work because htransaksi::find(auth()->user()->id) returns a finished data set - if this dataset is empty PHP's where() function failed because you tried to search something which is NULL

Comment: Yes, already check the authentication and already logged in. still did not work

Comment: @EricSugiharto this is not the essence of my fix, please read my code more closeley, there is also the solution to process everything correctly if the Shopping cart is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this line:

```
$status = htransaksi::find(auth()->user()->id)->where('Status','Open')->count();
```

if `htransaksi::find(auth()->user()->id)` returns `null` then your code will call `where` on `null` hence the error:

> Call to a member function where() on null

You can simply add a condition and do it separate:

```
$entryFound = htransaksi::find(auth()->user()->id);
if (empty($entryFound)) {
   //this means its returning null then handle that condition here
}

//if entry is found then leave the code as is:
$status = $entryFound->where('Status','Open')->count();
```